# EasyMock - Random tests failing - Matcher Expected

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I have a strange problem with EasyMock

This is the call I'm making which throws an `IllegalStateException : Matcher expected` as expected

```
expect(this.mock.expectedOperation(gt(0l), MyClass.class)).andReturn(createClassObject());
```

If I replace the above call with

```
expect(this.mock.expectedOperation(gt(0l), createClass(MyClass.class))).andReturn(createClassObject());

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Class<T> createClass(Class<T> clazz)
{
    return (Class<T>) EasyMock.anyObject();
}
```

**Most times i don't get an error**, but sometimes I do. It stays `IllegalStateException : Matcher expected ..`

Sometimes I get the `IllegalStateException : 2 Matchers expected 1 recorder` error for doing this:

```
MyClass object = createClassObject();
expect(this.mock.expectedOperation(anyLong(), anyLong()).andReturn(object);

public MyClass createClassObject() {
    // Actually sets properties and then returns
    return new MyClass();
}
```

But it runs when I do this:

```
expect(this.mock.expectedOperation(anyLong(), anyLong()).andReturn(createClassObject());
```

In the above example, sometimes the former runs and latter fails.

Sometimes this fails :

```
MyClass object = createClassObject();
expect(this.mock.expectedOperation(1, MyClass.class)).andReturn(object);
```

I have quadruple checked the reset, replay, verify calls. **These tests run sometimes and sometimes fail.**

If i run my unit test, it randomly fails at least once in one of the above listed situations. Why? How do I get it running?

EDIT : I'm using EasyMock version 3.1 and

```
MockedClass mock = EasyMock.createMock(MockedClass.class);
```

Comment: Any threads involved in the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. We can't use the gt(0) etc methods to pass parameters into the unit being tested.

In another test by my mistake had used :

```
service.performOperation(1, gt(0l));
```

service was not a mock, but the unit i was testing.

On checking the documentation I saw that gt(0l) returns 0, which was causing this test to pass by others to fail. (Dunno why?) Since tests are executed randomly, random conditions were failing.

Using the `reset(mocks..)` at the beginning of the tests did nothing to help.